# ¿como conectar con un proyecto existente de amplify?

Tags: aws, amplify

anteriormente ya había desplegado mi pagina. solo que luego mas adelante hice otro proyecto con amplify. pero cuando regrese al anterior proyecto para desplegar las nuevas modificaciones intente con un amplify publish

me salió esto `You have already connected branches to your Amplify Console app. Please visit the Amplify Console to manage your branches.`

Answer (score 0):

‎Desafortunadamente, debido a la limitación del servicio amplify Hosting, no será posible cambiar entre los tipos de alojamiento Manual <> CI / CD. La mejor manera de avanzar es eliminar la aplicación de consola de Amplify y crear una nueva.‎

En la página oficial de Amplify puede encontrar una mejor referencia:
[Amplify Hosting](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/hosting/hosting/#custom-domain-redirects-and-more)

Este es el texto:

> If you start from the Amplify Console's home page and connect your
> project's code repository (by clicking Connect app button), the
> frontend environment is created for your project once the workflow
> successfully completes. After setting up hosting in the Amplify
> Console, you cannot run the amplify hosting add command from your
> local installation of the Amplify CLI. To disable hosting, please
> visit the Amplify Console and disconnect the branch from the App
> settings > General page.